# Icons in NatTable cells

Tags: java, swt, jface, nebula, nattable

I'm in process of replacing JFace TableViewer with NatTable. In my implementation with TableViewer I have images in cells, and I have implementation of `ILabelProvider` which is aware of how to get image for concrete state of object at runtime. So I call `ILabelProvider.getImage(element)` from `ColumnLabelProvider`.

In NatTable I know the way to add an image via registring configAttribute against configLabel. And for configAttribute  I should explicitly tell what image to use. Surely I can create label for every state, register image for every label and use ConfigLabelAccumulator to tie it all togeather. But the amount of images is quite huge, and moreover I don't want to duplicate this logic. So is there more appropriate way for such a case? Just delegating to existing `ILabelProvider`?

Comment: See https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/491100/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases where you have quite some dynamic for retrieving the `Image` the label solution is insufficient (e.g. when thinking about a shop system with different images per row object). In such cases you typically implement a custom `ImagePainter` and implement the code the determine the `Image` to use in the `getImage()` method.

The following snippet can be used as a starting point where you only need to implement your custom logic to determine the `Image` to use. This way you only need to register one `ImagePainter`. In NatTable this is also done for some static images like for example the `TreeImagePainter`.

```
public class ContentDependentImagePainter<T> extends ImagePainter {

    IRowDataProvider<T> dataProvider;

    public ContentDependentImagePainter(IRowDataProvider<T> dataProvider) {
        this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected Image getImage(ILayerCell cell, IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {
        // get the row object
        T rowObject = dataProvider.getRowObject(cell.getRowIndex());
        Image result = null;

        // perform your custom logic to determine the Image

        return result;
    }
}
```